# Rename column names in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of columns in MySQL Table T1 with names like

```
A/B
C/D
E/F etc
```

I want to remove the '/' so that the names are `AB, CD, EF (etc)`

Is there a way(query) to rename all of them together rather than doing it one by one through `alter table`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to write a query that outputs the SQL, then copy-paste the output back into the command line.

Something like this:

```
select concat('alter table ', table_name, ' change ', column_name, ' ', replace(column_name, '/', ''), ' ', column_type, ';')
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'mydbname'
and column_name like '%/%';
```

I tested this SQL and it works

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. That way I have to copy paste all the column names too one by one..

Comment: Will this loop through all the columns or do I have to enter column name one by one

Comment: No - just run it (once) and copy the output and paste it back into the mysql command line. It will fix *all* your column names.

Comment: just don't do it on your live production database before testing it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table table_name
            change A/B AB varchar(20),
            change C/D CD varchar(20), 
            change E/F EF varchar(20)
```